# How can I fix NIntegrate::inumr warning message?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have this code:

```
fundamentalSol[p_, q_] := (1/(2 Pi))*Log[Norm[p - q]]
point = {1, 0.5};
GduY0[x_?NumericQ] := D[fundamentalSol[{x, 0} - point], x];
dGduY1[x_?NumericQ] := D[fundamentalSol[{x, 1} - point], x];
dGduX1[y_?NumericQ] := D[fundamentalSol[{1, y} - point], y];
I1 = NIntegrate[dGduY1[x]*x, {x, 0, 1}];
I2 = NIntegrate[dGduX1[y], {y, 1, 0}];
I3 = NIntegrate[dGduY0[x]*x, {x, 1, 0}];
H = -(I1 + I2 + I3);
N[H];
```

which is supposed to represent

$$H = -\left( \int_{0}^{1} x \frac{\partial{G([x,0] - p)}}{\partial{x}} dx + \int_{1}^{0}  \frac{\partial{G([1, y] - p)}}{\partial{x}} dy + \int_{1}^{0} x \frac{\partial{G([x,0] - p)}}{\partial{x}} dx\right)$$

where $G$ is the fundamental solution function described above. However, I get many warning messages:

[image]

I tried using `NumericQ`, but it doesn't seem to fix this issue. The integral doesn't need to be symbolic, I just want a numeric output.

Comment: The functions are `dGduY0`, `dGduY1`, and `dGduX1` do not give numerical results. Those functions use `fundamentalSol` wrong (with one argument, not two, as defined.) Also, you have to differentiate symbolically first and then evaluate the derivative with a numerical value.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
GduY0[0]
```

what gives an error message:

[image]

Now the definition of GduY0 is:

```
GduY0[x_?NumericQ] := D[fundamentalSol[{x, 0} - point], x];
```

For GduY0[0] this evaluates to:

```
D[fundamentalSol[{0, 0} - point], 0]
```

what explains the error message. To make this work you must introduce a dummy variable for the derivative like e.g.:

```
GduY0[x_?NumericQ] := D[fundamentalSol[{xx, 0} - point], xx]/. xx->x;
```

The next problem you have is, that Norm does not have a derivative. I think you mean "RealAbs" in the definition of `fundamentalSol`.